# Limit S3 bucket access to few specific roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a bucket policy by which I want to limit the current bucket access to 2 specific role only (any one having this role can access the bucket). Following is the policy I wrote but its not working. Any inputs on what might be wrong or probably the right way to do the same will be appreciated.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::role-tester",
                "arn:aws:s3:::role-tester/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "RoleID1:*",
                        "RoleID2:*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::role-tester"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you say RoleID1 and RoleID2, are you using the unique RoleID of the form AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q?

Comment: @jarmod Yes both are unique like what you mentioned.

Comment: Update: I just tried this and it seems to work. Are you sure that your role IDs are correct and that you are actually coming in with the role-based credentials (and not accidentally picking up other creds)?